# d3.scaleLog ticks with base 2

Tags: d3.js

I trying to produce ticks for `scaleLog().base(2)`.
Seems to be, it does not work correctly.
For instance, for the call:

```
d3.scaleLog().base(2).domain([50,500]).ticks(10)
```

I got:

```
[ 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500 ]
```

Which just linear placed ticks. For base(10) it works properly.

```
d3.scaleLog().base(10).domain([50,500]).ticks(10)
[ 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 ]
```

I using d3.js version 6.1.1.
I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything, but there is this line, inside the source code:

```
if (z.length * 2 < n) z = ticks(u, v, n);
```

Here, `z` is the generated array (in this case `[64, 128, 256]`), `n` is the required number of ticks (10), and `u` and `v` are the domain (50 and 500).

Because the number of generated ticks is too low, d3 defaults to a linear scale. Try one of the following instead:

```js
console.log(d3.scaleLog().base(2).domain([50, 500]).ticks(6));
console.log(d3.scaleLog().base(2).domain([32, 512]).ticks(10));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

If all parameters are variable, you could calculate the maximum possible number of ticks and use that as an upper bound:

```js
const domain = [50, 500];
const ticks = 100;

console.log(d3.scaleLog().base(2).domain(domain).ticks(ticks));

function getNTicks(domain, ticks) {
  const maxPossibleTicks = Math.floor(Math.log2(domain[1]) - Math.log2(domain[0]));
  return Math.min(ticks, maxPossibleTicks);
}

console.log(d3.scaleLog().base(2).domain(domain).ticks(getNTicks(domain, ticks)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But that I should do if all parameters - domain and number of ticks are variable?
I have to check ticks myself that they are linear?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I understand why my several other examples fails with `d3.scaleLog()`. Maybe it is not a solution (while `base` is also variable for me), but now I know that to do.